# revert source root folder to plain folder

Tags: intellij-idea, clojure

I created `.clj` script in the package `com.lapots.game.journey.math`. I saw notification that my `clj` file is not under source root.

At that time I did not know that I could make `clojure` folder as source root so I made my new package as source root.

[image]

However now I am unable to unbind `math` folder as source root and display it as package `com.lapots.game.journey.math` instead of just `math`. As result when I made an attempt to create `clojure namespace` with `clojure` kind

[image]

As a namespace in my clojure file inside `math` folder I've got just

```
(ns script)
```

instead of

```
(ns com.lapots.game.journey.math.script)
```

How to revert `math` folder from `source root` to a plain package?

Comment: Right clicking the directory in the project pane and selecting `Mark directory as -> Unmark as sources root` does not work?

Comment: Posted it as an answer after seeing that it worked.

Comment: @NESPowerGlove I did not know about `Mark directory as` function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click the directory in the project pane and select `Mark directory as -> Unmark as sources root`.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer:

1. Close IntelliJ
2. Delete the `.idea` directory & all contents
3. Re-start IntelliJ and select `File -> New -> Project from existing sources`
4. Navigate to your root directory and select `project.clj` and click OK.

I'm not sure about your namespace organization, but I assume you know it must match the directory hierarchy for both clojure and java.

Comment: Solution of @NESPowerGlove is simpler